# Decrypt using private key of SSL certificate installed on IIS in C#

Tags: c#, ssl, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I have a client who encrypts data using the public key of a SSL certificate. Details:

- IIS 10.
- .Net 4.8, C#
- SSL Certificate - 4096 bit, issued by CA.
- Client connects to my web API and sends encrypted data as parameter as a raw string using the public key of above certificate installed on my server.
- Client uses `RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256` for padding.

I have tried **(Code 1)**:

```
 public string DecryptRsa(string encrypted, X509Certificate2 x509Certificate2, RSAEncryptionPadding rSAEncryptionPadding)
        {
            var text = string.Empty;

            using (RSA csp = (RSA)x509Certificate2.PrivateKey)
            {
                byte[] bytesEncrypted = Convert.FromBase64String(encrypted);
                byte[] bytesDecrypted = csp.Decrypt(bytesEncrypted, rSAEncryptionPadding);
                text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesDecrypted);
            }
            return text;
        }
```

This gives error: Specified padding mode is not valid for this algorithm.

**Code 2**:

```
 public string DecryptRsa1(string encrypted, X509Certificate2 x509Certificate2, RSAEncryptionPadding rSAEncryptionPadding)
        {
            var text = string.Empty;
            var privateKey = x509Certificate2.GetRSAPrivateKey();
            var bytesData = Convert.FromBase64String(encrypted);
            var dataByte = privateKey.Decrypt(bytesData,rSAEncryptionPadding);
            text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataByte);

            return text;
        }
```

This gives the error: Parameter is incorrect.

I have tested using my public key for encryption and private key for decryption using OaepSHA1 padding and both above code work fine.

What am I not getting/doing wrong?

Comment: Try SHA 256: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.sha256?force_isolation=true&view=net-5.0

Comment: Thanks. I changed RSA to RSACng in the declartion and the cast , and in the first code and it works now with OAEPSHA256. Of course I changed the encrypt code to use the same. (RSACng). However, this works when I do it using my public key and private key. However when I try and decrypt a message(encrypted using my public key and OAEPSHA256 padding) from the client using the same technique, it fails. "Parameter is incorrect." Could it be that they are using Java and i am using c#?